# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hey sorry if I posted this in the wrong place, I just signed up here (:

So I'm working on this discord bot that sends a DM to everyone in my server, but whenever it fails to send a dm (probably because someone has dm's disabled or other reasons) I get this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

I want it so that it keeps sending messages to other users, even tho a error comes along. Which right now, it stops sending to other users when the error comes.

My Code:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('+dmall')) {
    try {
      message.guild.members.forEach(member =>
        member.send("test"))
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log('Couldnt send dm to a user!');
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

UnhandledPromiseRejection comes from your member.send method which returns a promise. To fix this I've added a .catch to the method

```js
message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
   member.send("test").catch(console.log('Couldnt send dm to a user!'))
});
```

However please note that sending a DM to everyone in a guild is strictly against Discord ToS, and you can be reported for mass DMing, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Yeah thank you that makes sence. Weirdly enough it still wouldn't work, I still get the same error message, been stuck on it forever /:

Comment: @ErikJohansson 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning comes from the member.send() method which actually returns a message promise. I've edited my code for you and this should clear the errors